# MySQL Result Filtration

Tags: mysql

I am trying to check if my `ID = 4` is within the RESULTS from MySQL but not in the last row and you probably don't understand what I am asking for lol, let me explain now:

I have `ID = 4` hard coded

I have MySQL `SELECT` statement LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE GROUP_ID = 10 AND ID = 4 AND (LAST OF THE RECORD FROM THAT GROUP_ID IS NOT (!=) (NOT EQUAL) (IS DIFFERENT) THEN 4
```

Cannot explain it simpler

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380263/how-to-check-if-id-is-within-all-the-results-form-mysql-but-not-in-last-row

Comment: What field should not be equal to 4? The ID?

Comment: YES ID FIELD MUST = 4 but not the last one from the group

Comment: how do you know which is the last record of the group? do you have an ID and you need to check the row with the maximum id for every group?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT
  yourtable.GROUP_ID,
  CASE WHEN
    SUM(yourtable.UID=s.max_uid AND yourtable.ID!=4)=1
    AND SUM(yourtable.UID!=s.max_uid AND yourtable.ID!=4)=0
  THEN 'okay' ELSE 'no' END
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN
  (SELECT GROUP_ID, MAX(UID) max_uid
   FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY GROUP_ID) s
  ON yourtable.GROUP_ID = s.GROUP_ID
GROUP BY
  yourtable.GROUP_ID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a530c/1).